# How to concatenate arrays based on number of pair formula

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have some arrays. Now, I want to concatenate these arrays based on this formula (`n*(n-1)/2`). Say, for example, I have 3 array and I can `concatenate` using the below function,

```
def concat():
  arrays = get_arrays() # this function returns some arrays
  array1 = array[0].reshape(-1, 1)
  array2 = array[1].reshape(-1, 1)
  array3 = array[2].reshape(-1, 1)

  concate_1_2 = np.concatenate([array1, array2], axis=1)
  concate_1_3 = np.concatenate([array1, array3], axis=1)
  concate_2_3 = np.concatenate([array2, array3], axis=1)
```

I do not need `concate_1_1, concate_2_2 or so on`. In the same way, I do not want `concate_2_1 and concate_3_1` because I already have `concate_1_2 and concate_1_3`. As I have 3 arrays, so based on the formula, I am getting `3*(3-1)/2 = 3` concatenation.

Now, the problem is, I can have a different number of arrays (not fixed only for 3 or 4). I can have 10 or 20 arrays. Then how can I tackle this dynamically (not writing manually, `concate_1_2`, `concate_1_3`, or so on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools` and `combinations`. One simple example is given below if you want to make combinations for 2 lists

code

```
from itertools import combinations
list(combinations(["a", "b", "c"], 2))
```

Output

```
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c')]
```

For more information see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution

```
import numpy as np;

def concat(array):
  (nR, nC) = array.shape; #Number of rows and columns
  concatenationContainer = np.zeros((int(nR*(nR-1)/2), 2*nC)); #add concatenate_1_2, concatenate_1_3, etc..
  counter = 0; #Index of the concatenationContainer array

  for row in range(nR): #For each row
    arrayRow = array[row]; #Obtain the next row
    for nextRow in range(row + 1, nR): #For each row that still wasn't concatenated with arrayRow
      concatenationContainer[counter] = np.append(arrayRow, array[nextRow]); #Concatenate
      counter+=1; #Update counter

  return concatenationContainer;

if __name__ == '__main__':
  example = np.zeros((4,4));
  example[1] = 1;
  example[2] = 2;
  example[3] = 3;  
  print(example);
  print(concat(example));
```

This runcode for example takes the following matrix:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [2. 2. 2. 2.]
 [3. 3. 3. 3.]]
```

and returns

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 2. 2. 2.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
 [2. 2. 2. 2. 3. 3. 3. 3.]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will let you know after running my code and will let you know.

Comment: Ok, check again the code I encountered a bad indentation in the updating of the counter (already fixed), and deleted the .reshape(-1,1) methods, because they are not necessaries.

Comment: @Servetti thank you. Code is working as per formula but I need to add them column-wise using `reshape(-1, -1)` and `axis=1`. Otherwise, my later code will not work! Like, I want to get `[[0, 1],[0,1],[0, 1],[0,1]]` instead of getting them `[0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]`